# I forgot the APNs certificate and now? (Push Notifications not working)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, certificate

My application is now in the Store. The problem is that `PushNotifications` does not work. I am using Parse.com `Framework` and before putting the app to the store the Push were working amazing! 
Now: the registration to receive the token works but the delivering of the push to the device does not.

I assume this is because... I've forgot to generate a Apple Production IOS Push Services Certificate. Infact, I have one for the developement but not for the production.

Now, I've just created it in the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" panel of the developer console. Downloaded it and added to the Keychain.

Now, I simply need to update my application with the same process that I've done with uploading it? (This is my first application ever developed and distributed in iOS)

Will the certificate be processed alone? Do I have to do something more?
I mean.. I've just created a new Apple Production IOS Push Services Certificate, signed, downloaded it and opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to create a provisioning profile using this certificate and re-submit the application.

The previous provisioning profile would be automatically invalidated.

You can request expedited review to Apple mentioning your problem. They should be completing the review process by same or next day.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have more than one certificate, create another and add it.